# Why does MSBuild sometimes ignore TargetFrameworkVersion?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I'm running msbuild commands in an automated batch file. Sometimes, msbuild is ignoring the target framework I specified. This seems to happen randomly, and often enough it is slowing down my work.

Here's the part of the csproj file that sets the target framework:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{1B0B7E3B-8708-4799-B768-1949DA9DD755}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>WithoutHaste.DataFiles</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>WithoutHaste.DataFiles</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

When I noticed this happening, I also started specifying the target framework in the msbuild command. This should override whatever setting is in the csproj file.

```
msbuild DataFiles.net20.csproj /P:TargetFrameworkVersion=v2.0;Configuration=Debug -fl -flp:logfile=logs\DataFilesOutput.net20.Debug.log;verbosity=normal
```

I've confirmed that the compiled library is targeting the wrong framework.
1) When the library is added to a .Net 2.0 project, I get an "indirect dependency" error. Looking at the library properties also shows "Runtime Version" set to "v4.0" instead of "v2.0".
2) Loading the assembly using reflection, the Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion is set to "v4.0" instead of "v2.0".

Any thoughts on why this would happen sometimes?

Comment: The compiler isn't rebuilding all the source files with new version of Net. I usually make a copy of the project bin folder and then delete the bin.  Then recompile which will force all source files to get compiled with new framework version.

Comment: I've added "clean and rebuild" to the command, and it seems to be compiling correctly now. "msbuild DataFiles.net20.csproj /t:Clean;Rebuild /P:TargetFrameworkVersion=v2.0;Configuration=Release -fl -flp:logfile=logs\DataFilesOutput.net20.Release.log;verbosity=normal"